# Using javascript function inside html form being echoed inside php

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, function

Forgive the title, this is the best way I can think to word my issue.

Basically, I have a html form inside some php code, but I need to include javascript functions (with parameters specified) inside the form. But I have an issue with the single and double quote marks escping the php code. See below:

```
echo'<form id="create_booking_form" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <div>Student Name: </div>
                    <input id="students_name" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('students_name')" maxlength="30">
                    <div>Parents Name: </div>
                    <input id="parents_name" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('parents_name')" maxlength="30">
                    <div>Parents Email Address: </div>
                    <input id="parents_email" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('parents_email')" maxlength="100">
                    <div>Booking Time: </div>
                    <input id="booking_time" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('booking_time')" maxlength="8">
                    <div>Comments / Questions: (max 255 characters)</div>
                    <input id="comments" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('comments')" maxlength="255">
                    <div>Password: </div>
                    <input id="password" type="password" maxlength="16">
                    <br /><br />
                    <button id="createbookingbtn" onclick="createbooking()">Submit your booking</button>
                    <span id="status"></span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>';?>
```

My issue is for example: onkeyup="restrict('students_name')"

If i use single quote to specify 'student_name' it escapes the echo command form the php code. If i use double quotes it escapes the restrict() function...

What can I do?

Much appreciated

Is anyone able to help me out here?

Comment: Just seperate the form and the JS, and use Jquery to attach the handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape your quotes by adding a single backslash before them..

Answer (score 5):

If your string is created with `'`'s, you can print a `'` character by escaping it: `\'`, and if it's created with `"`'s, then you can print it by escaping it to `\"`.

In your situation, however, I wouldn't do either. I'd just end the PHP tag and start it again:

```
?>
<form id="create_booking_form" onsubmit="return false;">
            <div>Student Name: </div>
            <input id="students_name" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('students_name')" maxlength="30">
            <div>Parents Name: </div>
            <input id="parents_name" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('parents_name')" maxlength="30">
            <div>Parents Email Address: </div>
            <input id="parents_email" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('parents_email')" maxlength="100">
            <div>Booking Time: </div>
            <input id="booking_time" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('booking_time')" maxlength="8">
            <div>Comments / Questions: (max 255 characters)</div>
            <input id="comments" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('comments')" maxlength="255">
            <div>Password: </div>
            <input id="password" type="password" maxlength="16">
            <br /><br />
            <button id="createbookingbtn" onclick="createbooking()">Submit your booking</button>
            <span id="status"></span>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
```

*But what when I want the HTML content to be in a variable?*

Just use an output buffer.

```
ob_start();
?>
    <p>Some HTML</p>
<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 4):

I would place the javascript in an external file, and have the php place the link to that file instead.

Answer (score 2):

Put a \ in front of the quote to escape:

```
echo'<form id="create_booking_form" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <div>Student Name: </div>
                    <input id="students_name" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement(\'status\')" onkeyup="restrict(\'students_name\')" maxlength="30">
```

etc