# Popup div running perfectly on JSFIddle but not on my webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This div is made to popup a message and be closed staright after. It works perfectly fine in JSFiddle but when I use it on my webpage it doesn't allow the user to close the message. I think it has something to do with the fact that I am doing through an `echo` but I can't see the issue. If there is a way to autoclose the message that would work then that would be great too. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code

```
echo "<div class='alert'>
          <span class='closebtn' onclick='this.parentElement.style.display='hidden';'>&times
          </span>New Customer saved successfully
      </div>";
```

```
.alert {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #324376;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Maybe share your fiddle as well?

Comment: Sure - https://jsfiddle.net/o8mny9rt/

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/s9RKk what PHP echos. If you put it into your fiddle, the fiddle Highlights where the error occurs. The parser closes the onclick to early.

Comment: You could escape the double quotes to mimic parts or all double quotes you have in your jsfiddle. `onclick=\"this.parentElement.style.display='none';\">`

Comment: And you are missing in your PHP code the `;` after your &times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using javascript function inside html form being echoed inside php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948327/using-javascript-function-inside-html-form-being-echoed-inside-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An even easier and, in my opinion, better solution would be to not echo the HTML through PHP in the first place. Just close the PHP block, write the HTML you want and then open the PHP tag again, if you need to.

```
<?php
// Some PHP code
?>

    <div class="alert">
        <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='hidden';">&times;
        </span>New Customer saved successfully
    </div>

<?php
// Some more PHP code
?>
```

The end result will be the same as using `echo`, but without the extra hassle.

The benefits of this are:

- You don't need to handle the quotes any differently than you would in any ordinary HTML file.
- Your IDE will be able to syntax highlight the HTML as well, making it easier to read and find potential typos etc.

Comment: Oh ok thats even better. So I could just write ```<?php echo "?> ``` (html code) ```<?php " ?> ``` and that would work fine?

Comment: @Joshuatb_02 - No, forget about the echo and the `"`. You should write the HTML _outside_ of any PHP context. I've updated the example for clarity.

Comment: @Joshuatb_02 - If any of the answers helped you solve your issue, please accept it so others know the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Sorry, just did that. I am new to Stack. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like :

```
this.parentElement.style.display='none'
```

Comment: The issue is not the html and js itself, but how it is echo-ed by PHP. That does not solve the issue.

Comment: I had it like this before an it did not work. I have figured out that the issue is with escaping the quote marks. The echo is surrounded by double quote marks so I am able to use single quote marks, but the single quote marks in the ```onclick``` function will not work unless everything else is double quote marks.

Comment: Try this : echo "<div class='alert'>
          <span class='closebtn' onclick='this.parentElement.style.display=``none``;'>&times
          </span>New Customer saved successfully
      </div>";

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<div class='alert'>
          <span class='closebtn' onclick='this.parentElement.style.display=`none`;'>&times
          </span>New Customer saved successfully
      </div>";
```

Comment: Wow, this was probably extremely easy for you but my brain could not comprehend how I should do it. Thank you :)

Comment: I already tested it in PHP and this one is working well.